# Why is it important to initialize Array Adapter inside the onCreate() method?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, oncreate

```
ArrayAdapter<String> bigSquash = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.adapter_xml, onPointString);
```

Whenever I initialize this array adapter outside the onCreate() method an error is generated, whereas when I initialize it in the onCreate() method no error is thrown.
So can anybody tell me why is this happening?

Comment: You need to post a screenshot of your code. This will help other answering your question

Comment: Consult: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then improve your question to explain 1) What is "outside the onCreate"? (show some code) and 2) What is "the error generated"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LayoutInflater.from(context) will be called in the ArrayAdapter constructor If the activity does not have onCreate, it will run out of exception ,

ArrayAdapter constructor code

```
private ArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource,
        @IdRes int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List<T> objects, boolean objsFromResources) {
    mContext = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mResource = mDropDownResource = resource;
    mObjects = objects;
    mObjectsFromResources = objsFromResources;
    mFieldId = textViewResourceId;
}
```

LayoutInflater.from code

```
public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater LayoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (LayoutInflater == null) {
        throw new AssertionError("LayoutInflater not found.");
    }
    return LayoutInflater;
}
```

activity.getSystemService code

```
@Override
public Object getSystemService(@ServiceName @NonNull String name) {
    if (getBaseContext() == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "System services not available to Activities before onCreate()");
    }

    if (WINDOW_SERVICE.equals(name)) {
        return mWindowManager;
    } else if (SEARCH_SERVICE.equals(name)) {
        ensureSearchManager();
        return mSearchManager;
    }
    return super.getSystemService(name);
}
```

So you need to call after activity onCreate。

Comment: But why will it run into an Exception if there is no OnCreate() call before it and what kind of exception will be thrown and should we catch it? I know these are a lot of questions but please answer as many as you can!

Comment: [please see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67517501/why-is-it-important-to-initialize-array-adapter-inside-the-oncreate-method/67528711#67528711)

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the initialization of the variable mBase of the Activity parent class ContextWrapper

Activity start process

`ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity  -> Activity.attach -> Activity.attachBaseContext -> ContextThemeWrapper.attachBaseContext -> ContextWrapper.attachBaseContext -> ContextWrapper.mBase init`

Activity's onCreate() method will be called after attach()

If you call Activity's getSystemService() before mBase has been initialized, an exception will occur because the mBase variable is empty

`new ArrayAdapter(activity) -> LayoutInflater.from(context) -> Activity.getSystemService -> Activity.getBaseContext is null  throw IllegalStateException`

If you need more detailed information, please check the startup process of Activity